# Is this proof of Hilbert's basis theorem unclear/making a mistake?

Tags: ring-theory

I am reading  the [second proof of Hilbert's basis theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_basis_theorem#Second_proof)

The author writes: "... and let $b_k$  be the set of leading coefficients of members of $a$ whose degree is $\le k$. As before, the $b_k$ are left ideals over $R$."

But how can this be?

For example, we don't satisfy an ideal property: if $g_1, g_2 \in R[x]$ with $\deg g_1=k$  and   $\deg g_2=1$ then $\deg g_2g_1 =k+1 >k$ so that the leading coefficient of $g_2g_1$ is not guaranteed to be in $b_k$ but the leading coefficient of $g_1$ is in $b_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That leading coefficient absolutely *is* in $\mathfrak b_k$. If $g(x) = cx^j + \cdots$ is in the ideal $\mathfrak a$ of $R[x]$ with degree $j \leq k$ and leading coefficient $c$, then for each $r \in R$, $rg(x) = rcx^j + \cdots$ is in $\mathfrak a$ since $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal in $R[x]$. So if $rc \not= 0$ then $rc$ is also a leading coefficient of a polynomial in $\mathfrak a$ with degree at most $k$. Thus for $c \in \mathfrak b_k$ and every $r \in R$ with $rc  \not= 0$, $rc \in \mathfrak b_k$. Now if $rc = 0$, then $rc$ is also in $\mathfrak a$ since $\mathfrak a$ should be defined as the leading coefficients of polynomials in $\mathfrak a$ of degree at most $k$ *together with* $0$. (The omission of $0$ as an element of $\mathfrak a$ is a mistake in the proof you cited.) Thus every $R$-multiple of an element of $\mathfrak b_k$ is also in $\mathfrak b_k$.

So if you try to justify a claim one way and it doesn't work out, that doesn't mean the claim is actually wrong.  Maybe there is another way to explain it that does work.

By the way, this approach to proving Hilbert's basis theorem is due to Artin, according to van der Waerden [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82253306.pdf).